# Blazor Server UI PlotlyChart not updating after page change or refresh

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a pre developed blazor server side project right now. In the home page I have a PlotlyChart which shows some data to the user

`<PlotlyChart style="height: 60%; width: 100%;" @bind-Config="config" @bind-Layout="layout" @bind-Data="@DataContext.Data" @ref="@DataContext.Chart"/>`

Whenever I hard code data, The chart works perfecly, But when I extract data from the database the chart shows the data but after refreshing the page or redirecting to another page and come back the chart shows empty.

First I add the `StateHasChanged` to my code and tried different lifecycles method but I wasnot successful to resolve the issue.

I thought maybe my data array is empty but it is not because I can write it in the console.

Comment: Are you using the Update or React functions to update the state?

Comment: What is DataContext.Data and how is it populated?  When you return to the page what is the state of DataContext.Data?

Comment: @maciek No its a blazor (razor) page, I don't use react functions to update the state

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis The DataContext carries the data from the database, And I'm sure it's not empty.

Comment: @Amir  There is a React() function you have to call for the change to take effect if you change data that the chart is displaying... The function Update() does the same. I assume you are using https://github.com/LayTec-AG/Plotly.Blazor

Comment: https://github.com/LayTec-AG/Plotly.Blazor/blob/main/Plotly.Blazor/PlotlyChart.razor line   line 143 (React) and 252 (Update)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem after spending a day on that.

I suppose to re-invoke the js library after the page is rendered.

Here is the complete code for that

```
Config config = new Config()
    {
        DisplayModeBar = Plotly.Blazor.ConfigLib.DisplayModeBarEnum.False,
        Responsive = true
    };
Layout layout = new Layout()
    {
        Margin = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.Margin
        {
            B = 15,
            T = 5,
            L = 85,
            R = 2
        },
        YAxis = new System.Collections.Generic.List<YAxis>
    {
        new YAxis
        {
            Title = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.YAxisLib.Title
            {
                Text = "kWh",
                Font = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.YAxisLib.TitleLib.Font
                {
                    Family = "Font Awesome 5 Free",
                    Size = 12
                }
            }
        }
    }
    };

protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    var scatter = new Scatter
    {
        Name = "ScatterTrace",
        // Here we'll use dates on the X axis. More info here: https://plotly.com/javascript/time-series/
        X = DataContext.XData,
        Y = DataContext.YData,
        HoverInfo = Plotly.Blazor.Traces.ScatterLib.HoverInfoFlag.Y,
        Line = new Plotly.Blazor.Traces.ScatterLib.Line
        {
            Color = "rgb(3, 181, 133)" // switch over to variable
        }
    };

    InvokeAsync(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            await DataContext.Chart.AddTrace(scatter);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message, "Caught exception while adding new plot trace");
        }
    }).IgnoreAwait();

    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but a very different cause.

I was mapping a chart configuration to chart component like this:

```
<PlotlyChart @bind-Config="chartConfig" @bind-Layout="chartLayout" @bind-Data="chartData" @ref="chart" />
```

I was then setting the chartData during OnParametersSetAsync
This resulted in the issue described.

If, however, I explicitly set the data via the ref chart. Data all worked as expected.